# Dovecot version upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and dovecot version is 1.2.9, I want to upgrade my dovecot version from 1.2.9 to **2.1.7**

Comment: Obviously it's not that smooth as upgrading the package

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install a more recent version of a package that is not available in the repositories, you need to find/create the suitable `.deb` file(s). Alternatively, you can always download the source code from the official website and build it yourself.

Comment: step 1: 
wget http://dovecot.org/releases/2.1/dovecot-2.1.7.tar.gz

Step 2:
tar -zxvf dovecot-2.1.7.tar.gz

Step 3:
./configure
make
sudo make install

Step 4:
sudo /etc/init.d/dovecot restart

Step 5:
dovecot --version